# if statement does not work in codeigniter3 framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have written some code that checks if there are lessons show `tr` tag if not, do not show. However, if statement does not work despite the empty result.
Here it shows properly because this instructor has lessons[image]

However, another instructor does not have any lesson, for this reason here it should not show `<tr>` tag, but it shows empty tr
[image]

Where can be the problem?

Here is my model:

```
public function get_instructors_lessons($slug = FALSE) {
        if ($slug === FALSE) {
            $this->db->join('courses', 'instructors.id = courses.instructor_id');
            $query = $this->db->get('instructors');
            return $query->row_array();
        }

        $this->db->join('courses', 'instructors.id = courses.instructor_id', 'left');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('instructors', array('instructors_slug' => $slug));
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

And here is my view:

```
<?php if(count($lessons)>0): ?>
  <?php foreach($lessons as $lesson): ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a class="lessonsofinstructors" href="<?= site_url('/courses/'.$lesson['courses_slug']);?>">
          <?= $lesson['title'] ?>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?= $lesson['duration'] ?> Months</td>
      <td>
        <?= $lesson['begining'] ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @u_mulder edited

Comment: This happens because `count($lessons)` is greater then 0. Print it to see the value you have.

Comment: it shows 1 in the output

Comment: `var_dump($lessons)`

Comment: @u_mulder it shows this https://yadi.sk/i/0oXxzh-d3MxQ4c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154617/discussion-between-javid-abbasov-and-u-mulder).

Comment: Your problem is in left join. Left join takes data of instructor no matter if he has courses or not.

Comment: Yes, i have changed it and it has worked! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join takes data of instructor no matter if he has courses or not. So you need another join type, I suppose default one will fit:

```
public function get_instructors_lessons($slug = FALSE) {
    if ($slug === FALSE) {
        $this->db->join('courses', 'instructors.id = courses.instructor_id');
        $query = $this->db->get('instructors');
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    // no join type here
    $this->db->join('courses', 'instructors.id = courses.instructor_id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('instructors', array('instructors_slug' => $slug));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```